# How to filter list and Document library in java-script

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, javascript, document-library, sharepoint-rest-api

How to filter the list and document library from SharePoint using base-type?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to filter the list collection using base list template, you can do it like:

**Get Generic/Custom Lists**:

```
<siteUrl>/_api/web/lists?$filter=BaseTemplate eq 100
```

**Get Document libraries**:

```
<siteUrl>/_api/web/lists?$filter=BaseTemplate eq 101
```

| List Type | Template ID |
| --- | --- |
| Generic / Custom list | 100 |
| Document Library | 101 |
| Survey | 102 |
| Links | 103 |
| Announcements | 104 |
| Contacts | 105 |

You can find other `ListTemplateType` at: [ListTemplateType enumeration - Members](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ee541191(v=office.15)#members)

Answer (score 0):

You could add filter parameters in the end of the REST API end point to filter list and document library.

For list；

```
/_api/web/lists?$filter=BaseType eq 0
```

For document library:

```
/_api/web/lists?$filter=BaseType eq 1
```

Reference: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ee540560(v=office.15)